# Setting MySQL C++ Connector to correctly receive Cyrillic characters

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I need to use the MySQL C++ Connector 1.1.12 to insert Cyrillic characters but when I use this string:

```
con->setClientOption("OPT_CHARSET_NAME", "utf8");  // I tried also utf8mb4 
con->setClientOption("characterSetResults", "utf8");
```

I receive this error code: `MySQL error code: 1366`.
How do I correctly set up the communication with the DB?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your connection successful without Cyrillic characters? Also, have you looked into [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-using-character-sets.html)?

Comment: yes the connection to the DB works but I can't get the unicode characters accepted?